# Workgroup connection: You may not have permission

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, workgroup

I have two Windows XP computers connected through an Ad-Hoc network, computer A creates the network and B connects to it. Both computers are on the Mshome network and have file and printer sharing enabled, and they can ping one another through the adhoc network.

The result is that computer A can see computer B, but B cannot see A in the workgroup. But when A tries to access B I get a "you might not have permission to access" error telling me to contact the administrator.

I tries to google the error, but most posts talk about problems connecting different versions of Windows to each other. I tried turning off the firewalls on both machines and checking if the required services are running. Nothing helped.

Please excuse my ignorance on Windows networking, I haven't used Windows in around 10 years.

Comment: Have you ensured you have a matching user name and password on both computers?

Comment: Nope, but in my experience that is not a requirement to share data through a windows network. Am I wrong?

Comment: It often has to be that way in a Workgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Before going ahead backup your registry data or create a system restore point.

- Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedit**, and then click **OK**
- Locate and then double-click the following registry subkey:

  > **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa**
- On the right side, double-click **restrictanonymous**.
- Make sure that the value in the Value data box is set to **0**, and then click OK.
- Close Registry Editor and Restart the computer.

There are several other reasons that you get this error, you can find some resources [here](http://support.microsoft.com/search/?adv=1)

Comment: Both computers had restrictanonymous set to 0.

Comment: @afiefh:As said earlier that these may or may not work,please try these resources which i found in microsoft support.
[How to troubleshoot home networking in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308007)
[You receive an "Access is denied" error message when you try to access shares on a Windows XP Home Edition-based computer that is connected to a network](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281248)
[You cannot access shared files and folders or browse computers in the workgroup with Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318030)
one more [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870702)